# Need an opinion on a method for pull data from a file with Perl

Tags: perl, ssh

I am having a conflict of ideas with a script I am working on. The conflict is I have to read a bunch of lines of code from a VMware file. As of now I just use SSH to probe every file for each virtual machine while the file stays on the server. The reason I am now thinking this is a problem is because I have 10 virtual machines and about 4 files that I probe for filepaths and such. This opens a new SSH channel every time I refer to the ssh object I have created using [Net::OpenSSH](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aOpenSSH). When all is said and done I have probably opened about 16-20 ssh objects. Would it just be easier in a lot of ways if I SCP'd the files over to the machine that needs to process them and then have most of the work done on the local side. The script I am making is a backup script for ESXi and it will end up storing the files anyway, the ones that I need to read from.

Any opinion would be most helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the VM's do the work locally, it's probably better in the long run.

In the short term, the ~equal amount of resources will be used, but if you were to migrate these instances to other hardware, then of course you'd see gains from the processing distribution.

Also from a maintenance perspective, it's probably more convenient for each VM to host the local process, since I'd imagine that if you need to tweak it for a specific box, it would make more sense to keep it there.

Aside from the scalability benefits, there isn't really any other pros/cons.

Comment: I see, so each of my ideas has pretty much the same outcome because I still have to open the SSH object to transfer the files anyway, right?

Comment: Yep, if you were using a different VM technology you could effectively avoid the SSH. For example OpenVZ can give you multiple *nix VMs - and allows you to access the VM file system from the host.

Comment: Well thats the thing, I am not actually accessing the VM. I am accessing all of the file inside the hypervisor that make up the VM and looking for specific data in the configuration files.

Comment: Ah, so if it's in the host filesystem, why not access it directly, or am I missing something?

Comment: Well I am doing that with SSH, what spawned my question is that each virtual machine has its own folder that houses the config files. In order for the my script to look into each folder I use a series of loops while runs through a config file and grabs the connection parameters for SSH and connect each time to dig up a VM then I .... think it disconnects. What I am trying to do is make the amount of SSH objects that are spawned as low as possible to make the script and lean as possible. So I was wondering if just transferring the files over to the script host would be better.

Comment: About your above comment, I would just drop my script onto the VMware ESXi server, but I can't for 2 reasons. 1. No Perl interpreter. 2. The file system is wiped everytime you reboot unless you store the scripts on remote storage. So I decided to go with a remote solution rather than resorting to shell script which other than python is all the "service console" which is the shell supports. Very limited options, but full SSH is enabled but then I am still limited but the incredibly stripped version of BusyBox they use to reduce the load on the server so the Hypervisor is not dragged down.

Comment: Granted if I was not so cheap / poor I would just buy the remote script tools that VMware sells which I think start at $995 for ESXi essentials.

Comment: Python is pretty well featured, and not particularly difficult to use, how about doing the operation with that?

Comment: I don't know, I guess it is because I have put so much work into making this perl script work correctly. Plus my ultimate goal is to make a Debian vm appliance to run everything out of. I guess in the end I am trying to find solutions around the common problem other scripts of my kind run into. The main one being, what to do with the script.

Comment: "I guess in the end I am trying to find solutions around the common problem other scripts of my kind run into. The main one being, what to do with the script." --- I'm sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: @Solignis, Net::OpenSSH does not open a new connection for every command run. It uses the same connection to run all of them (as far as you also reuse the Net::OpenSSH object!).

Comment: @Salva, I am glad it uses the same connection for each command. I really like your OpenSSH module keep up the good work.